CORS error trying to fetch Graph-Client data
I am trying to make a graph request for: getSharePointSiteUsageDetail. This gives me a redirect URL which then should download a CSV containing the report.
export const fetchAuditLogs = async (context: WebPartContext) => {
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error("WebPartContext is not available.");
    }

    try {
        const graphClient: MSGraphClientV3 =
            await context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient("3");

        const initialResponse = await graphClient
            .api(`/reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(period='D7')`)
            .get();
        
        const redirectUrl = initialResponse?.location; 

        if (!redirectUrl) {
            throw new Error("Redirect URL not found in response.");
        }

        const response = await  fetch(redirectUrl);

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Failed to fetch CSV file. Status: ${response.status}`);
        }

        const csvText = await response.json();

        return parseCSV(csvText);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching audit logs:", error);
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch audit logs: " + error.message);
    }
};

this is my code. I get an OK response at first, but when accessing the redirect URL i get:
Access to fetch at 'https://reportsweu.office.com/data/v1.0/download?token='<token> (redirected from 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(period='D7')') from origin 'https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
The permissions are setup correctly
I hope someone can help me with that
I tried using different clients for authorization like msGraphClient, spHttpClient and aadClient with no luck.
